# Adding docs to elasticsearch via API, discovering them via kibana. How?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I typically insert data (logs) into elasticsearch via logstash plugin.  Then, I
can search them from kibana.

However, if I try to intert data in elasticsearch programatically (in order to
skip filebeat and logstash), I cannot find the data in kibana.

This is what I tested:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(["XXX"], ...)
doc = {
    "@version": 1,
    "@timestamp": datetime.now(),
    "timestamp": datetime.now(),  # Just in case this is needed too
    "message": "test message"
}
res = es.index(
    index="foobar-2019.05.13", doc_type='whatever', id=3, body=doc,
    refresh=True
)
# Doc is indexed by above code, as proved by
# es.search(
#    index="foobar-*", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}}
#)
```

I added the index pattern `foobar-*`` to kibana in "Index Pattern -> Create
index pattern".  Then, I can use "discover" page to search for documents in that
index.  But no documents are found by kibana, even if those exist in
elasticsearch.

What I am missing?  Are there any mappings that should be configured for index?

(note: using 6.x versions)

UPDATE: example of doc indexed, and mapping of index

```py
# Example of doc indexed
{'_index': 'foobar-2019.05.13', '_type': 'doc', '_id': '41', '_score': 1.0,
 '_source': {'author': 'foobar', 'message': 'karsa big and crazy.  icarium crazy.  mappo big.',
             'timestamp': '2019-05-13T15:52:19.857898',
             '@version': 1, '@timestamp': '2019-05-13T15:52:19.857900'}}

# mapping of foobar-2019.05.13'
{
  "mapping": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "author": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample document that is currently in the index as well as the current index mapping?

Comment: @Val, I updated the question with the info you suggested

Comment: ok that looks good. Are you sure that the date/time picker in the Discover view is properly adjusted to show your documents?

Comment: @Val, yes (I even tried the "Last 5 years" option, since I only have 3 docs indexed).  I suspect there is a relevant mapping that logstash is setting in the other indexes but I am clueless about.  I can try to replicate all mappings in my new index, but that option is like shooting in the dark...

Comment: Are you sure that you have selected a date field (either `timestamp` or `@timestamp`) when creating your index pattern?

Comment: Yes, I selected @timestamp, as I see that indices created by logstash use it (kibana asked me to choose one of those two, so they were detected)

Comment: Ok, next step, can ou copy/paste the request that Kibana is making, you can find it by clicking on the Inspect button (left of the period picker) and then the Request tab

Comment: I found the issue... there was a 2 hour timezone difference between host were code is running and elasticsearch/kibana hosts.  So, I was inserting 2 "hours in the future" and searching "anywhere in the past".  I will close the question.

Comment: Ok, note that you can also define a custom timezone in Management > Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue... there was a 2 hour timezone difference between host were
python code is running and elasticsearch/kibana hosts.

So, since I was using `datetime.now()`, I was inserting documents with a timestamp "hours in the future", and I was searching for them "anywhere in the past".

If I look for them in the future (or, if I wait for 2 hours without updating
them), they are found.

Embarrassing mistake on my side.

Fix for me was to use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`

Comment: Good catch, indeed!